# function that returns the condition number in matlab

Tags: matlab

Could anyone help with a function that returns the condition number of a matrix based on the euclidean norm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://teal.gmu.edu/ececourses/ece699/notes/note4.html) is a good explanation about condition number and [here](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/matlab/ref/cond.html;jsessionid=ff5b094e9865cbf90507f43528ab) is how you do it in Matlab.

```
c = cond(X)
```

Comment: good answer, but as the question is tagged with homework I suspect that the OP is supposed to implement the function rather than just use it.

Comment: The implementation is straight-forward as well using the description from the first link. A naive implementation: `norm(X) * norm(inv(X))`. A better one would use svd.